# How to access javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE from the view/inside code?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

[My Setup: Java EE 6 application, with EJB3.1, CDI/Weld, JSF2 running on Glassfish 3.0.1]

I just read about the Faces ProjectStage on [this page](http://java.dzone.com/news/jsf-20-new-feature-preview-ser), which is a cool thing. So i configured it in my Web.xml, setting it to Development:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>   
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now i want to access the ProjectStage from the JSF view (setting the visibility of specific UI components accordingly).

Therefore i already tried things like an outputtext with the value `#{javax.application.projectStage}`, which seems to be null, and i also tried many other variants, with no success. I even don't manage to access the ProjectStage from within Java code (then i could expose it myself with a Bean).

How can i access the PROJECT_STAGE value inside my application?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Got it. From the view, it can be accessed like:

```
<h:outputText value="Stage:#{facesContext.application.projectStage}"/>
```

In the code, it can be accessed like:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getProjectStage().toString()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably exposed via the `initParam` [implicit object](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij). Failing that, check the [ExternalContext](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using initParam pre-defined JSF EL variable

```
#{initParam['javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE']}
```

Comment: It would only return `null` when there's no context param definied. Also, it does not cover cases when the project stage is been set by JNDI. I'd prefer the `#{facesContext.application.projectStage}` instead as it returns the final value which is actually been used by JSF, regardless of where it has been configured.

Comment: I confirm this answer doesn't work if you set Project Stage using JNDI.